# How can i get all the users and their reward points from branch or atleast tag a name with them?

Tags: android, branch.io

I am using branch.io for the referral programmes in my android application.

Is there any way I can know the all the user's points and I need them to monitor and analysis, to disable and enable the programmes.

I am new to branch.io & I didn't find any relevant info on the branch documentation.

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first set up an identity for each user to track the various activities of each user in your app. You can set the identity in your Android app as:

```
Branch.getInstance().setIdentity("your_user_id");
```

To learn more you can check out the Branch documentation [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#track-users).

You can then use Branch's public API to access the referral rewards or the referral history for each user by proving the identity to set earlier.

```
curl -XGET 
'https://api.branch.io/v1/credits?branch_key=<Branch_key>&identity=<user_ID>'
```

You can also read the entire referral history for this user by using the `/credithistory` endpoint

```
curl -XGET 
'https://api.branch.io/v1/credithistory?branch_key=<branch_key>&identity=<user_ID>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the REST API info